# FormatException when using "X" for hexadecimal formatting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, string-formatting

I took the following code from [HexConverter - Unify Community Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=HexConverter)

```
string hex = color.r.ToString("X2") + color.g.ToString("X2") + color.b.ToString("X2");
```

This gives me the exception:

```
FormatException: The specified format 'X2' is invalid
```

I tried then to use `"D"` but even this threw an error. The only thing working is `"F` for formatting float numbers.

*Go to declaration* reveals mscorlib.dll/System/Single.ToString (string) in assembly browser - sounds good so far.

Googling for *monodevelop string format hex* or similar search strings did not show anything interesting  regarding restrictions in MonoDevelop.

So is there anything to prepare, initialise, ... before I can get a simple hex value Conversion?

**[Update]**
Color is a struct in Unity:

```
public struct Color
{
    public float r;
    public float g;
    public float b;
    // ...
```

Taking dtb's answer I finally got it working using:

```
    int r = (int)(color.r * 256);
    int g = (int)(color.g * 256);
    int b = (int)(color.b * 256);
    string hex = string.Format ("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
```

So I missed the fact that `Color` defines its components as `float` instead of `int` and the integral types thing dtb has mentioned.

**[Update-2]**
More elegant solution:

```
Color32 color32 = color;
string hex = color32.r.ToString ("X2") + color32.g.ToString ("X2") + color32.b.ToString ("X2");
```

Comment: Can we see your declaration of color? or is it directly form the wiki?

Comment: As a simple test, I used `System.Drawing.Color.White.R.ToString("X2")` and received as String return `FF`.  So yes, what is "color" in your example?

Comment: @emd It's Unity's `Color` struct. In the wiki they use `Color32` which is different. This was the point in combination with dtb's statement about type `Single`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString):

> The hexadecimal ("X") format specifier converts a number to a string of hexadecimal digits. The case of the format specifier indicates whether to use uppercase or lowercase characters for hexadecimal digits that are greater than 9. For example, use "X" to produce "ABCDEF", and "x" to produce "abcdef". **This format is supported only for integral types.**

`Single` is a floating-point type, not an integral type.

Use an `Int32`:

```
int value = 10;
string result = value.ToString("X2");
// result == "0A"
```

Comment: Many thanks. Using int it works like expected - see my updated question.